# Issue while picking file from main/resource folder of maven folder structure

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to fetch a file from src/main/resources folder.
Earlier it was working fine but recently it has started picking that file from some target location (target/classes/filename.xml) (I did not create that file in target folder).

```
File xmlFile = new File(ReadXMLFile.class.getClassLoader().getResource(“filename.xml”).toURI());
```

Code that I am trying is:

```
 File xmlFile = new File(ReadXMLFile.class.getClassLoader().getResource(“filename.xml”).toURI());
```

Expected: it should pick the file from **src/main/resources/filename.xml**
actual: it is picking the file from target/classes/filename.xml

**Additional Info:** My code is in `ReadXMLFile.xml` and its under the below folder structure
com.qa.smartcomm.util
    ReadXMLFile.xml

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: **Target** folder is automatically created by maven, and each time `clean` command is run it is re created a new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have structure(Module) like below:

```
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── somepackage
│       │       └──Main.java
│       │           
│       │               
│       │              
│       └── resources
│           └── filename.xml
└── pom.xml
```

---

```
File xmlFile = new File(String.valueOf(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.xml")));
```

Answer (score 2):

Target Folder is automatically by maven. It copies the resources from  *src/main/resources* to *target/classes/* together with the compiled java classes from **src/main/java**.

If you run your program *target/classes* is the root of you **classloader**.

Comment: Ok. thanks for clarifying. Both are having difference versions. the change which i do in src/main/resources/filename.xml does not sometimes reflect in target/classes/filename.xml hence causing issue

Comment: how can i make sure both the folder structure have same version?

Comment: It is done by default from maven if you execute a phase which includes the goal resources:resources for example mvn install should do the job. Or you could execute the goal manual by typing mvn resources:resources

Comment: Would be nice if you accept the answer because I need some points :-)